# Angular js is undefined in IE8 When view page

Tags: angularjs

i am using angularJS 1.6.4 but when we view the page in IE8 we are getting the below errors

Message: 'angular' is undefined

Comment: The HTML page is working fine in Chrome.Additional error in IE8 as below.
Message: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery and pointing to../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Well... don't use IE8. IE8 is not supported by AngularJS. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: support for IE 8 was removed in Angular 1.3 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie.  No currently supported OS actually runs IE 8, so it's really not something people are offering support for, at this point.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, IE8 is not supported by AngularJS, but there is a npm package called [angularjs-ie8-build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-ie8-build) which can be used, however they also not guarantee that everything will work.

In order to use this package, you need :

- es5-shim
- jQuery 1.*
- AngularJS 1.4.* build from this repo (some poly-fills are baked in and minor fixes to enable IE8 support)

You need to add this in your head tag before loading angular :

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.0.5/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .ng-hide {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

For more information read the package description :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-ie8-build